# If $z^2 =f(x,y)$ then find $∂z/∂x$

Tags: calculus, partial-derivative

If $z^2 =f(x,y)$ then find $∂z/∂x$

how to find $∂z/∂x$

Comment: Differentiate both sides partially with respect to $x$. Then solve the resulting expression for $\partial z/\partial x$.

Comment: $2z$ = $ ∂x f(x,y)$ is that true ?

Comment: No. The left hand side by the chain rule is $2z \cdot \partial z/\partial x$. The right hand side is $\partial f/\partial x$. Now set those two equal to each other and solve for $\partial z/\partial x$.

Comment: $2z\frac{\partial z}{\partial x}=\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}\implies \frac{\partial z}{\partial x}=\frac{1}{2z}\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}$ ...now substitute what you know $z$ to be...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$2 zz_{x}=f_{x}(x,y)$ and $z_{x} =\frac{f_{x}(x,y)}{2z}$